# Uncompress .tar.gz format getting error "tar: Unrecognized archive format"

Tags: macos, compression, tar, archiving

I've downloaded a ".tr.gz" file with a size of 10 GB from [here](https://hkbuedu-my.sharepoint.com/personal/shwang_link_hkbu_edu_hk/_layouts/15/onedrive.aspx?originalPath=aHR0cHM6Ly9oa2J1ZWR1LW15LnNoYXJlcG9pbnQuY29tLzpmOi9nL3BlcnNvbmFsL3Nod2FuZ19saW5rX2hrYnVfZWR1X2hrL0VvaWVJYk5nVGpOR2gwLXNic3gza2o4Qnh6dXJOSDk5NGt3WDJSNm1qZjNxMWc%5FcnRpbWU9MzBfZTN2YlAyRWc&id=%2Fpersonal%2Fshwang%5Flink%5Fhkbu%5Fedu%5Fhk%2FDocuments%2FHDU%5FHKBU%5FCOVID%2DCT%2Fdataset%5Fcleaned%2Fdataset%5Fcleaned%2Etar%2Egz%2Epartab&parent=%2Fpersonal%2Fshwang%5Flink%5Fhkbu%5Fedu%5Fhk%2FDocuments%2FHDU%5FHKBU%5FCOVID%2DCT%2Fdataset%5Fcleaned) (after downloading completed, I renamed it and deleted .partb to become dataset cleaned.tar.gz) while I'm trying to uncompress it with this command:

```
tar -xvzf dataset_cleaned.tar.gz
```

I'm getting this error:

```
tar: Unrecognized archive format
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```

Note: I'm using Macbook and I downlanded the file on external harddrive with a size of 2T

Comment: Try in a terminal window: gunzip filename.gz (https://www.tunesbro.com/extract-gz-file-on-mac.html) P.S. I am a Windows & Linux user.

Comment: @vssher returns an error "file not in gzip format"

Comment: Read and follow what HarryMC has written, he knows what he is talking about... P.S. I am a Windows & Linux user...

Answer (score 2):

If you had partA & partB, you were supposed to `cat` them together.

All you have there is one half of the archive, which is unusable alone.

Comment: Files that do not rely on each other, each file contains folders of images, when I'm trying to cat them together the terminal suspended

Answer (score 0):

The files are uncompressed correctly by the Keka software.
The tar command on the Mac terminal can't compress them.